# How to make a get request in Angular to receive Wordpress's Gravityforms data?

Tags: javascript, angular, wordpress, gravityforms

I'm trying to receive entries from Gravityform Rest API V.2 in Angular by making a get request, except I keep getting 401 http error responses, while my console logs ('Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'livesite' from origin 'localsite' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.'). I have used 'basic authentification' to make the request.

https://docs.gravityforms.com/rest-api-v2/#basic-authentication
https://docs.gravityforms.com/rest-api-v2/#get-forms-form-id-entries

I succesfully used the Postman application to make post/get requests with the same credentials. I have added SSL to my domain and allowed "Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *" in Wordpress.

```
// Link to form #1 
const url = 'https://livesite.com/wp/wp-json/gf/v2/forms/1/entries';

// Base64 key with : and keys are set in environment.ts
const key = btoa(this.publicApiKey + ':' + this.privateApiKey);

// Create HttpHeaders  
const headersObject = new HttpHeaders().set('Authorization', 'Basic ' + key);
const httpOptions = { headers: headersObject };


// Get 
this.http.get(url, httpOptions)
  .subscribe(
    response => {
      console.log('response', response);
    },
    error  => {
      console.log('error', error);
    }
  );
```

Comment: You should add a proxy to your Angular app to connect https://juristr.com/blog/2016/11/configure-proxy-api-angular-cli/

Comment: You can add the property `withCredentials: true` on your `httpOptions` object and try again.